# Convert timezone of a pandas column datetime64 from UTC to America/New_York

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime64

I have tried the following to change timezone Pandas dataframe:

```
print(df['column_datetime'].dtypes)
print(df['column_datetime'].tz_localize('America/New_York').dtypes)
print(df['column_datetime'].tz_convert('America/New_York').dtypes)
```

Which gives me:

```
datetime64[ns, UTC]
datetime64[ns, UTC]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 9484, in tz_convert
    ax = _tz_convert(ax, tz)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 9472, in _tz_convert
    ax = ax.tz_convert(tz)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/extension.py", line 78, in method
    result = attr(self._data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 803, in tz_convert
    "Cannot convert tz-naive timestamps, use tz_localize to localize"
TypeError: Cannot convert tz-naive timestamps, use tz_localize to localize
```

Two questions:

1. Why `tz_localize` does not return `datetime64[ns,America/New_York]`?
2. Why `tz_convert` says that timestamp is tz-naive when `dtypes` shows UTC?

---

EDIT:
answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979079/5328289) actually solves this by using `tz_convert`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series(np.datetime64('2005-01-03 14:30:00.000000000'))
y = x.dt.tz_localize('UTC')
z = y.dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
z
---
0   2005-01-03 09:30:00-05:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, America/New_York]
```

Comment: Have you got some sample data?

Comment: You are right, sample data and reproducible example is required, I will prepare an example that can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is only possible if your dataframe has a tz naive datetime index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_datetime': pd.to_datetime('2005-01-03 14:30', utc=True)},
                  index=[pd.to_datetime('2005-01-03 14:30')])

print(df['column_datetime'].dtypes)
print(df['column_datetime'].tz_localize('America/New_York').dtypes)
print(df['column_datetime'].tz_convert('America/New_York').dtypes)
```

Answers to your questions:

**1. Why `tz_localize` does not return `datetime64[ns,America/New_York]`?**

`tz_localize` localizes the **index**, not the values of the series (for the latter you need the `dt` accessor, as you already found out). You can verify this by printing `df['column_datetime'].tz_localize('America/New_York').index.dtype` which is `datetime64[ns, America/New_York]`. You printed the types of the values which didn't change in this operation.

This behaviour is clearly described in the [documentation of `tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html):

> This operation localizes the Index. To localize the values in a
> timezone-naive Series, use `Series.dt.tz_localize()`.

**2. Why `tz_convert` says that timestamp is tz-naive when `dtypes` shows UTC?**

Same reason as 1. - it tries to convert the index, which has no timezone. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_convert.html) is not so clear here as for `tz_localize`.